# Getting [object HTMLUListElement] instead of contents of the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to display to lists but with the code I have all i get back as the output is [object HTMLUListElement]. If I just append 'value' itself then it out puts the ul's but if i put it in a variable first i just get back [object HTMLUListElement]:

```
var listFind = $('.yCmsContentSlot'),
    navLinks = listFind.find('ul'),
    navLinksTotal = navLinks.length,
    listContainer = $('.search-error__content-bottom-list');

    if (navLinksTotal >= 5) {
        navLinksTotal = 3;
    }

    var navBlockSize = 12 / navLinksTotal;

    $(navLinks).each(function(key, value) {
        var navListBlock = '<div class="col-md-' + navBlockSize + '">' + value + '</div>';
        listContainer.append(navListBlock);
    });
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery selector returns an array-like object containing native references to any elements that matched the selector.

You are then iterating over this array-like object via `each()`.

With this in mind you can discern that a reference to the each UL is passed, in turn, to the callback. So `value` is a (poorly named) variable pointing to the element itself. What you're currently seeing is the result of trying to output - i.e. convert to a string - an object, rather than a property of it.

Extrapolating further, you just need to know how to get the inner HTML of an element.

This is done via `value.innerHTML`.

Better would be to rename `value` `element` - and while we're talking sensible naming, `navLinks` is probably not the best name for a variable that stores not link but, rather, *list* elements.